# Beginner - Python 2.7.2, ArcGIS 10.1 Multiple 'or' conditions, same action

Tags: python, arcgis, conditional-statements

I started using Python on Friday, so I'm at a pretty basic level.have an .mdx with several layers, and I wish to remove particular named instances at a stroke.

So, I want to select the layers with a 'multiple or' and remove them from the ToC (not delete them from disc). Neither of the 'if' lines below work.

```
# Remove source features from TOC
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):

 if (lyr.name == "name1") or (lyr.name() == "name2") or (lyr.name() == "name3"

 if (lyr.name == ("name1" or "name2" or "name3"):

   arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you getting an `invalid syntax` error? You are missing some right parentheses on both of your `if`s. Also, sometimes you do `lyr.name` and sometimes you do `lyr.name()`. Which one is it?

Comment: lyr.name or lyr.name()  - I don't klnow - what is the difference?

Comment: @Bruce Mitchell: lyr.name is either a property or a class variable, lyr.name() is a method (hopefully returning the name).

Comment: Thank you Michel. As you see below, your explanation about lyr.name() was key to solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the algorithm but I think you need the following:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyr.name() in ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']:
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayout(df, lyr)
```

Comment: Thaks for your rapid response. Investigating now.

Comment: Finally got it to work: 

... for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
...     if lyr.name in ['AllCENTROIDS','AllPOLYGONS','POLYGONSsenzaCENTROIDS']:
...         arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bruce Mitchell: Glad it works now ... it would be kind if you upvote all correct answers and select one of the answers as your solution.

Comment: Couldn't get the pythonic solution to work. It wasn't happy with 'arc.mapping'.  Your first solution worked when I used lyr.name rather than layer.name(). Thank you.

Comment: Yes I see it ... it does not work the way I wrote but I don't think it can be written otherwise ... so I removed it.